# What are the naming conventions for Mac and iOS frameworks?

Tags: ios, macos, naming-conventions

Or put another way:

What are the 'Kit', 'Toolbox', 'Core', and 'Foundation' prefix/suffix naming conventions in Mac and iOS frameworks?

Going through Apple's frameworks these prefixes and suffixes seem to follow a pattern but I haven't found anything [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CocoaApplicationLayer/CocoaApplicationLayer.html) explaining the exact differences. This is the basic pattern I see:

- **Foundation** - low level, C/Objc
- **Core** - mid, C/Objc
- **Toolbox** - general services
- **Kit** - high, Objc

Also there is some inter mixing of these names that I guess means the framework is a mix between both levels of abstraction. For example **Core Foundation** and **Core Audio Kit**.

Also do popular third party frameworks follow these conventions very closely? RestKit fits well since it is high level however CorePlot seems like CoreKit would have been a better if not for google collisions with the javascript library of the same name.

Comment: Here is a [list of prefixes](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ChooseYourOwnPrefix), but the only ones I have stumbled across in almost 4 years of iOS development are CF (Core Foundation), NS (NextStep heritage), CC (cocos2D) and KK (Kobold2D)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't name it a convention, it has to do with the Architecture of Cocoa. I'm gonna try to answer using iOS Architecture but it's the same for Mac.

Architecturally iOS is divided into 4 main layers

- Core OS: It't basically the kernel
- Core Services: This is where **Foundation** and **Core** Foundation lays, so it manipulates Strings, Collections, etc. it also manipulates hardware features like GPS here you will find **Core** Motion, **Core** Location, but also **System** Configuration. This layer is also known as *Core Frameworks layer* cause it handles the base frameworks of the OS.
- Media: As you may guess it handles media (Audio, Video & Graphics) So you will find frameworks like **Core** Graphics, **Core** Animation, **Core** Audio but also **OpenGL** ES and **AVFoundation**
- Cocoa Touch: Here you will find high level frameworks that supports applications, some of the frameworks are the UI **Kit**, the Game **Kit** but also the Message **UI**, Address Book **UI** and even single names like **iAd** or **Social** frameworks

Every layer depends on the previous one. So why does Apple choose that names? Well normally they use the word *Core* to refer to the base of the frameworks (the kernel), generally this are low level frameworks that directly manipulate basic operations (in hardware or from the OS). A clear example is Foundation that is basically an object oriented wrapper of *Core Foundation* or AVFoundation that relies on *Core Animation*, *Core Audio* and *Core Media* so as you can see foundation suffix is not the lowest level, it depends on the architecture. Normally you would use the word *toolbox* to provide interfaces for accessing certain types of external files/devices or support for managing them. Normally you would use the word *kit* when providing a set of tools that you can use right out of the box on your Apps.

In short, the goal of naming a framework is to understand the clases it contains based on the architecture's design. But as I said before I wouldn't say it's a 'convention' it's more like a 'good practice'.